# How to stop searching device in Webcam Capture?

Tags: java, webcam, video-capture, java-8

I've just started to use Webcam Capture and found out that after starting Webcam class the searching of the devices never ends. How is it possible to stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what do you mean that "searching of the devices never ends". Does it hang or simply search new device again and again?

In first case, when search devices hangs, you should fill new bug ticket on the Webcam Capture [github project page](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture). There was a bug which caused devices search to fail and it was already fixed, so if you are using 0.3.10-RC6, you should not observe it. If you are using this version and problem still persist, then again, please fill the bug report and wait for the response from the developers. Link to fill new bug report (don't forget to include logs from console):

> https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/new

In second case, if you mean that search new devices is executed again and again, and you see same message in the log from SLF4J every 3 seconds, then you simply have to disable webcam discovery service. From the [Webcam Capture API Handbook](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture/src/etc/resources/webcam-capture-handbook.doc?raw=true) for version 0.3.10 (page 20):

```
WebcamDiscoveryService discovery = Webcam.getDiscoveryService();
discovery.stop();
```

I hope this information can help you.

Comment: It's just what I need. Thanks!